# A question about "the requirement that all Americans"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

**[In the first paragraph of this article,](https://www.yahoo.com/news/tax-bill-guts-unpopular-obamacare-insurance-mandate-081231479--politics.html)**  I am afraid I am unable to properly grasp its meaning.

> Republicans didn't get their wish to repeal former President Barack Obama's health care law, but the tax bill barreling toward a final vote in Congress **guts its most unpopular provision, the requirement that virtually all Americans carry health insurance**.

So the new tax bill, which is a hot topic these days, "guts" the most unpopular provision. And what exactly is it?

What exactly is the requirement of the health insurance?

Am I wrong to think that this line,

> its most unpopular provision, the requirement that virtually all Americans carry health insurance.

sounds a bit strange? Because the bill would "gut" some provision, which in the structure of this sentence would be the object, which should be described in the latter part of the sentence, here.

> **the requirement that virtually all Americans carry health insurance**.

But seeing as the writer is adding the words "health insurance" here, I am not quite able to comprehend what exactly the new bill "guts". Had the sentence been:

> *the requirement that virtually all American health insurance carry*

I would probably have been able to understand much more clearly.

Can anyone help me understand the meaning and structure of the phrase in bold above?

---

Thank you very much for your answer.

I have a question, now, regarding the nouns in question, which are, provision and the requirement, you tell me

> There are two noun phrases here, they are placed next to each other, in apposition. The noun phrase starting "the requirement" will tell us what the provision is.
>
> **"the requirement" will tell us what the provision is.**

So, I think, as you say later on, the relative clause needs to describe what the requirement is more about detail of it.

However, or therefore, **that** relative clause still sounds strange to me.

> **that all Americans carry health insurance.**

Should there be, for example, a preposition, for example, with, between the verb "carry" and the noun phrase "health insurance", I would probably understand. **Because by adding the preposition with, the requirement is given more information, which is the requirement is something that all American ( need ) to carry "with" health insurance.**

I hope you understand me. Let me upvote you for you answer.

Comment: I think it reads OK as is, but I don't quite understand what your concern is. The phrase "the requirement that virtually all Americans carry health insurance" describes the "provision". The "unpopular provision" was in the health care law, and the tax bill is gutting it.

Comment: Had that sentence been "the requirement that virtually all American health insurance carry", then I would've understood vividly.

Comment: Putting _carry_ at the end is not grammatical, as it is a verb.  The _that_ introduces a relative clause.  The subject is _virtually all Americans_ and the object is _health insurance_.  The verb _carry_ must go in between.

Comment: No, please go back to the entire paragraph. Congress guts its most "unpopular provision", which is Object, and after the comma, the requirement = unpopular provision, so that after *that*, a sentence needs to explain what kind of unpopular provision aka the requirement. So, ending by the verb would be natural, I think.

Comment: No, your change doesn't work, but the original is grammatical and makes sense.  You should edit the question to contain what you think it should say, though, because that makes it very clear what your problem is, so someone should be able to write a good answer explaining it.  By the way, *that* here doesn't introduce a relative clause as the comment above claims – it introduces a subordinate content clause, which we can tell because there is no gap (nothing is missing, and it has the subject verb and object all present and in the usual order).

Comment: I would also recommend making your title more descriptive. There is some advice in [How can I write a better title for my ELL question?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2630/).

Comment: I'm sorry Im' still unable to understand. Is snailplane talking that the "unpopular provision" is not equal with the "requirement"?

Comment: I've given a shot (attempted) to clarify the question, and write a more descriptive title. I *think* I understand what the OP is asking, but it still needs a little refinement, which I cannot provide.

Comment: Hello :) As I already mentioned, I *think* I understand your question but your suggestion in bold is not grammatical in English. If you change the 2nd sentence in bold to `…that all American health insurance must be carried` I think it would be clearer, it would definitely be grammatical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure if the verb 'd better be passive, but I am happy that we have something in common^^.